# How can I view all of the flights between two cities across all dates?

Tags: air-travel, routes

I believe that the standard routes of carriers between two semi-major US cities always maintain the same route number (e.g. UA3271), and day of the week. I'm looking at planning travel for an interview, so dates are [currently] quite flexible (as in at least one month's range). Since that's the case, there are other constraints that go into my choice of flights. One would be the option to fly out of my home city, land in the interview location, conduct the interview, and fly out in the same day. I figure: if I can view the schedule for flights (i.e. routes) between the two cities, I can make an educated request for days of travel. Yes, I could likely work with the interview scheduler (and I will), but I'd like to be proactive in suggesting some dates to achieve my goal, as well as learn this skill for myself in the future. Thus:

Where can I view the daily routes and times for flights between two cities, on whatever rotating basis (e.g. day of the week) they may be on?

Comment: Your belief and assumption that route numbers don't change is wrong, as flight numbers and times can change without notice.  While long haul flights (JFK-LAX, etc) often have a lower risk of changed flight numbers and short hauls have a higher risk, there is no guarantee of no change for either.

Comment: You're making this harder than it needs to be. No secrets here... online booking shows all available flights in and out of your destination. Just use an online ticket booking site, and see what they have available for same day in and out.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my situation. I'm looking for the standard routes, regardless of whether they are booked for a given day or not. Online booking will not show me flights that are full - and I don't know my dates in advance.

Comment: @Tom True, they can change without notice, but I'm referencing the *standard* routes to/from (mostly small cities), where there are <5 flights per day. I don't have a good example at the moment, but when I did traveling more in the past out of small airports, each time I'd see the same flight numbers listed on old-school plastic/felt signs ... because the numbers didn't change.

Comment: Wow plastic & felt signs.  User3.1415927 things have come a long way since the dark ages of travel.  I fly frequently in and out of smaller and medium sized cities.  I have on numerous occasions gotten an email from the airline telling me that my booking on flight 3472 has been changed to flight 5673 departing 12 minutes later.  And checking online find that flight 3472 no longer flies to East Botswana it now goes to West Angkor.

Comment: I'm not saying I can't get an update in email/text. I'm saying the flights are consistent enough that staff leave the signs up from day to day, week to week... Your snarkasm isn't really helpful.

Comment: @user3.1415927 What good does knowing the schedule of a full flight do you? Just see what's available to book, and propose those dates. Pretty simple. I think you're way overthinking this.

Comment: @SnakeDoc It's quite simple really: imagine any number of personalized scenarios where it's beneficial to weigh cost/benefit, and usually having all of the information will help the user to make the best decision. E.g.: If I fly for business and must arrive before 10am for a meeting, it might make sense for me to fly that morning ... however, if I find that waking up at 3am to get to the airport and through security with enough time to make a 5am flight is unfavorable, it's to my advantage to know that there is a flight the night before that arrives just after my usual 10pm bedtime.

Comment: @user3.1415927 And online booking doesn't give that to you? This is a problem that's been solved...

Comment: @SnakeDoc No, online booking *does not* solve this for [user]. Online *will not* show flights that are not available for a given day.

Comment: @user3.1415927 what good is that to anyone? You want to propose dates for this interview... you can only propose dates that 1) Have Flights Available... and 2) Aren't Full. Your offline attempt at seeing routes does neither of these... it just tells you what routes a given airline runs, but not availability or if that route even still has a plane flying it on any given day. It's not like a bus route where it's set in stone. Flights change based on demand all the time. Basically... you're doing this wrong.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is to find the published timetable for your airline. For example, I did this recently and used the [Qantas Timetable](http://www.qantas.com/travel/airlines/timetable/global/en) for flight planning. The PDF version (link at left) was most helpful, as it shows all the flights on a weekly basis in a very compact form.

Following your UA example, the [United Timetable](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/travel/timetable/Default.aspx) is a web search but I don't see a PDF version. The [Delta flight schedules](https://www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedulesSetup.action) can be downloaded as a PDF.

Comment: While that's useful for instances when I know a which carrier I want to use, my usecase is not knowing carrier...

Comment: @GregHewgill can you please answer the comment on top of this one?

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the things [Expertflyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/) will do for you.

[image]

Comment: Can I use that site without making an account? Doesn't seem like it, big downside if you ask me.

Comment: Agreed; the lack of use without an account makes this untenable.

Comment: Eh, any serious traveler will sooner or later realize you need Expertflyer :) There's just too much value. And I am not an employee just a satisfied customer. Note I posted the ITA Matrix solution as well.

Comment: +1 to ExpertFlyer, it knows about flights that other search engines don't, such as those in Uzbekistan Airways.

Answer (score 5):

[ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) can do this -- it can do everything else so why not this? Unclick the "
Only show flights and prices with available seats" checkbox and you will get a list of flights: [image]

Comment: Holy smokes. Best flight tool I've found yet. Doesn't list all of the flights across all of the days (like a 'matrix', ironically), but is really useful!

Comment: [expertflyer.com will give you the actual timetable filed by the airlines with IATA for any given city pair. It's not a free service though.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141514/without-dates-how-can-i-find-out-efficiently-and-freely-when-an-airlines-f#comment351338_141514). can you respond pls?

Answer (score 4):

If there are nonstop flights available between your hometown and the interview location, you can also try so search for the flight schedule of the airport. To give some examples of German airports:

- Stuttgart airport has a pretty good online search, allowing you to search connections without specifying a date: http://www.stuttgart-airport.com/arrival-departure/flightplan
- Munich airport has a PDF of the entire schedule available (https://www.munich-airport.de/_b/0000000000000001689285bb58ee1e46/Flugplan-Sommer-2017---Druckversion.pdf)
- Frankfurt airport also allows to search for flights without specifying a date, however, the results are listed separately for each day, not in the compact form used by Stuttgart airport (https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/flights---more/flights.html)

Comment: So far this is the closest thing ... at least in terms of clues. I was able to search for the string "flight schedule #city", and found http://flightaware.com/live/airport/KXNA/scheduled as an example. This isn't overall the solution, but it's a good place to start.